# Flatten Dictionary Python challenge

Tags: python, interview-questions

I have a question about [this coding challenge for "Flatten a Dictionary"](https://github.com/NeverDoubtTheWorm/Pramp/tree/master/Flatten_Dictionary):

> Given a dictionary dict, write a function flattenDictionary that
>   returns a flattened version of it .
>
> If you’re using a compiled language such Java, C++, C#, Swift and Go,
>   you may want to use a Map/Dictionary/Hash Table that maps strings
>   (keys) to a generic type (e.g. Object in Java, AnyObject in Swift
>   etc.) to allow nested dictionaries.
>
> Example:
>
> Input:
>
> ```
> dict = {
>     "Key1" : "1",
>     "Key2" : {
>         "a" : "2",
>         "b" : "3",
>         "c" : {
>             "d" : "3",
>             "e" : "1"
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> {
>     "Key1" : "1",
>     "Key2.a" : "2",
>     "Key2.b" : "3",
>     "Key2.c.d" : "3",
>     "Key2.c.e" : "1"
> }
> ```
>
> Important: when you concatenate keys, make sure to add the dot character between them. For instance concatenating Key2, c and d the result key would be Key2.c.d.

```
def flatten_dictionary(dictionary):

  def items():
  # loop through each item inside the dictionary k, v
      #Appending
      # check if the sub-key and sub-value are 
      # inside the flatten_dict(value)
      # join on subkey array
      # add to result
      # clear out prev_keys
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
      if isinstance(value, dict):
        for subkey, subvalue in flatten_dictionary(value).items():
          if key == "":
            yield subkey, subvalue
          yield key + "." + subkey, subvalue

      else:

        yield key, value

  return dict(items()) 


# test cases 1

dictionary2 = {
            "Key1" : "1",
            "Key2" : {
                "a" : "2",
                "b" : "3",
                "c" : {
                    "d" : "3",
                    "e" : "1"
                }
            }
        }


# output: {
#             "Key1" : "1",
#             "Key2.a" : "2",
#             "Key2.b" : "3",
#             "Key2.c.d" : "3",
#             "Key2.c.e" : "1"
#         }

print(flatten_dictionary(dictionary2))
```

Comment: Flattening a dictionary is a weird request. How do you handle key collisions? Overwrites really don't make sense, because they are implementation dependent (at least before Python 3.4, I believe where `dict` behaves like `OrderedDict`), so you can't definitively say across python versions how it should behave. Your `key + '.' + subkey` also doesn't generalize, but keys are not always strings.  Anything immutable that defines `__hash__` and `__eq__` can be a key.

Comment: @BaileyParker Or the problem has to be properly described. The way it stands at the moment justifies all your concerns. This is what SO would classify as *too broad*. Imho always.

Comment: You should at *least* add a link to the problem description, where these ambiguities might be resolved already.

Comment: I updated the problem description so it is clear what the question is asking me to do.

Comment: Your question currently leaves some things to be desired. I'd recommend taking a look at [Simon's Guide to posting a good question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6429/31562). In particular, you could add a reason for why you are posting your code here, what do you want from a review? Also, how much have you tested this code?

Comment: I Added link to the challenge:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### 1. Bugs

1. The special case for empty keys:

   ```
   if key == "":
     yield subkey, subvalue
   yield key + "." + subkey, subvalue
   ```

   is missing an `else:` and so leads to items appearing twice:

   ```
   >>> flatten_dictionary({"": {"a":1}})
   {'a': 1, '.a': 1}
   ```
2. Even if we fix the bug by adding the `else:`, there's still a problem. Consider this example:

   ```
   >>> flatten_dictionary({"a": {"": {"b": 1}}, "": {"a": {"b": 2}}})
   {'a.b': 2}
   ```

   What happened to the `1`? Ignoring the empty string keys has led two different keys to be collapsed into one. It would be better to remove the special case for empty strings, so that:

   ```
   >>> flatten_dictionary({"a": {"": {"b": 1}}, "": {"a": {"b": 2}}})
   {'a..b': 1, '.a.b': 2}
   ```
3. Python has a limited stack, but dictionaries can be nested arbitrarily deeply:

   ```
   >>> d = {}
   >>> for i in range(1000): d = {'a':d}
   ... 
   >>> flatten_dictionary(d)
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "cr186013.py", line 22, in flatten_dictionary
       return dict(items()) 
     [... many line omitted ...]
     File "cr186013.py", line 13, in items
       for subkey, subvalue in flatten_dictionary(value).items():
   RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
   ```

   This problem can be avoided using the [stack of iterators](http://garethrees.org/2016/09/28/pattern/) pattern.

#### 2. Other review points

1. The comment does not match the code: there is nothing in the code corresponding to "check if the sub-key and sub-value are inside the flatten_dict(value)" or "join on subkey array" or "clear out prev_keys". Incorrect comments like this are worse than useless: they make it harder to understand and maintain the code.

   Did this comment describe an earlier version of the code, and then you changed the code but forgot to edit the comment? It is worth getting into the habit of changing the comment first so that you don't forget.
2. The construction of the result keys has unnecessary quadratic runtime. For example, in this situation:

   ```
   >>> flatten_dictionary({'a': {'a': {'a': {'a': {'a': {'a': 1}}}}}})
   {'a.a.a.a.a.a': 1}
   ```

   there is only the need to concatenate one result key (`'a.a.a.a.a.a'`), but the code concatenates five result keys: not just the one that we need, but `'a.a'`, `'a.a.a'`, '`a.a.a.a`' and `'a.a.a.a.a'` as well. The way to avoid this is to keep a stack of dictionary keys currently being visited, and use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) on the stack when you need to concatenate the result key.

#### 3. Revised code

```
def flatten_dictionary(d):
    result = {}
    stack = [iter(d.items())]
    keys = []
    while stack:
        for k, v in stack[-1]:
            keys.append(k)
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                stack.append(iter(v.items()))
                break
            else:
                result['.'.join(keys)] = v
                keys.pop()
        else:
            if keys:
                keys.pop()
            stack.pop()
    return result
```

Comment: I don't think it can pass this test cases: Input: {"":{"a":"1"},"b":"3"}
Expected: {"a":"1","b":"3"}
Actual:  {'.a': '1', 'b': '3'}

Comment: See §1.2 for why special handling of empty strings is a bad idea.